# How do I display the language name instead of language code in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a built in templatetag to display a language name instead of language code?

Eg.
I'm currently getting 'en' but I want 'English'

Comment: I guess by tag he means "template tag"

Comment: What are you currently using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The i18n package provides the "get_language_info" tag

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_language_info for "en" as lang %}
{{lang.name_local}} ({{lang.code}})
```

will return:

```
English (en)
```

Substitute "en" in the above example for your template attribute

Eg. **profile.language** for my custom profile model was the attribute that was returning "en" by default - now I have a much prettier display for the language attribute

---

The above answers op question and comments from @art_hq supply an additional more generic solution using `profile.language` as follows:

```
{% get_language_info for profile.language as lang %} {{ lang.name }}
```

Comment: to clarify - if you get language from `profile.language` your code should be like:  `{% get_language_info for profile.language as lang %} {{ lang.name }}`

Comment: To further clarify - if you get language from profile.language, then you can use the Django get function called `get_x_display()`. So in your .html template when you have your instance you can write `{{profile.get_language_display}}`